# Using lightbox with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, lightbox

I am building a website and I am trying to use lightbox to display the photos in an enlarged form. I am unable to align the images on the form of the .aspx content page. I am also using a master page so I am wondering if I need to put all of the lightbox information on the master page or if I should put them on the content page itself.

When I place all of the images onto the content page they overlap one on top of the other.
Here is my code for the MASTER PAGE:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.master" 
Inherits="MadelinesFarm._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Madeline's Farm</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#images a').lightBox();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div align="center">
<br />
<p align="center">

        <asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" AlternateText="Madeline's Farm" 
            DescriptionUrl="~/Default.aspx" Height="80px" HotSpotMode="Navigate" 
            ImageUrl="~/Images/title.png" Width="625px" 
            ToolTip="Madeline's Farm Homepage">
            <asp:RectangleHotSpot HotSpotMode="Navigate" 
                NavigateUrl="Default.aspx" Target="_parent" Right="625" Top="80" />
        </asp:ImageMap>
&nbsp;<br />
</p>
<hr />
<p align="center">

        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" BackColor="#CC9900" BorderColor="Black" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Yearlings" Width="125px" 
            PostBackUrl="~/Yearlings.aspx" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" BackColor="#CC9900" BorderColor="Black" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Foal Arrivals" Width="125px" 
            PostBackUrl="~/FoalArrivals.aspx" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" BackColor="#CC9900" BorderColor="Black" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Photo Gallery" Width="125px" 
            PostBackUrl="~/PhotoGallery.aspx" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" BackColor="#CC9900" 
            BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Directions" 
            Width="125px" PostBackUrl="~/Directions.aspx" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" BackColor="#CC9900" 
            BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Contact Us" 
            Width="125px" PostBackUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" />

</p>
</div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<hr />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for the CONTENT PAGE:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"   
MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master" CodeBehind="PhotoGallery.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="MadelinesFarm.WebForm4" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<div id="images">
<a href="Images/FlagPole.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/FlagPole.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BirthingBarn.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BirthingBarn.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/FarmMares.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/FarmMares.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy2.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy2.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy3.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy3.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy4.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy4.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy5.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy5.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy6.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy6.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy7.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy7.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/BigBoy8.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/BigBoy8.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Desire.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Desire.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Desire2.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Desire2.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Desire3.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Desire3.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/DSC_0643.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/DSC_0643.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/DSC_0644.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/DSC_0644.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/DSC_0646.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/DSC_0646.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/DSC_0648.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/DSC_0648.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/DSC_0655.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/DSC_0655.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/MadelinesBigBoy.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/MadelinesBigBoy.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Mares2.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Mares2.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Mares3.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Mares3.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Mares4.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Mares4.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Mares5.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Mares5.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Ranger.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Ranger.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/Ranger2.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/Ranger2.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="Images/RittersDragon.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group">
<img src="Images/RittersDragon.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</a>

</div>


</asp:Content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to show you how to create a lightbox effect with simple CSS only. Try putting your images in a table of some kind and creating a margin or buffer so they don't overflow.

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.img_container{
/*position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 180px; height: 100px; margin-right: 10px;*/
display: table-cell;
height: 100px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 180px;}

.imgdivbox a {
    width: 190px;
}
```

and

```
<div class="imgdivbox">
    <div class="img_container">
        <a title="Your_Title" href="Link2pic1.JPG" data-lightbox="container_name">
        <img src="Link2pic1.JPG" data-lightbox="container_name" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="img_container">
        <a title="Your_Title" href="Link2pic2.JPG" data-lightbox="container_name">
        <img src="Link2pic2.JPG" data-lightbox="container_name" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```